# Kotin Jetpack Compose, OutlinedTextField not updating value in Viewmodel

Tags: kotlin, mvvm, android-jetpack-compose

I am not able to update the class from viewModel

**viewModel.update( "numberplate", it )** in HomeScreen.kt

Source code: Home Class

```
data class Home (
    var numberplate:String
    ) {
    constructor() : this("")
}
```

HomeScreen.kt

```
@SuppressLint("UnusedMaterialScaffoldPaddingParameter")
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(navController: NavController)  {
    val viewModel: HomeViewModel = viewModel()
    LaunchedEffect(key1 = "request_home") {
        viewModel.load()
    }
    Scaffold(
        topBar = { TopAppBar(
            backgroundColor = AppPrimary,
            contentColor = AppBackground,
            title = { Text("example") },
            navigationIcon = if (navController.previousBackStackEntry != null) {
                {
                    IconButton(onClick = { navController.navigateUp() }) {
                        Icon(
                            imageVector = Icons.Filled.ArrowBack,
                            contentDescription = "Back"
                        )
                    }
                }
            } else {
                null
            }
            ,
            actions = {
                Text(text = "New",
                    fontSize = 18.sp,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(8.dp)
                        .clickable {
                            viewModel.new()
                        })
            }
        )  },
        content = {
            HomeForm(viewModel = viewModel, navController = navController)

        }

    )
}

@Composable
fun HomeForm(viewModel: HomeViewModel, navController: NavController) {

    val state by viewModel.state.observeAsState(viewModel.state.value)
    val df = DecimalFormat("#0")

    Column(
        Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(20.dp),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top

    ) {

        OutlinedTextField(
            value = state?.numberplate ?:"",
            onValueChange = {
                Log.d("home","screen numberplate $it")
                viewModel.update( "numberplate", it ) },
            label = { Text(text = "Numberplate") },
            colors = TextFieldDefaults.outlinedTextFieldColors(
                unfocusedBorderColor = AppPrimary
            ),
            placeholder = {
                Text("required")
            },
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
        )



    }
}
```

HomeViewModel.kt

```
class HomeViewModel(application: Application) : BaseViewModel(application) {

    val state: MutableLiveData<Home> by lazy { MutableLiveData<Home>() }
    private val errorHandler = CoroutineExceptionHandler {_, exception -> exception.printStackTrace() }

    fun load() {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO + errorHandler) {
            // TotoGet Homme
            val home = Home("HX13LUB")
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                state.value = home
            }
        }
    }


    fun update(key: String, value: String) {
        Log.d("home","viewmodel $key = $value")
        when (key) {
            "numberplate" -> {
                state.value?.numberplate = value
            }
        }
    }

    fun new() {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO + errorHandler) {
            val home = Home("")
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                state.value = home
            }
        }
    }
}
```

BaseViewModel.kt

```
abstract class BaseViewModel(application: Application): AndroidViewModel(application), CoroutineScope {
    private val job = Job()

    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = job + Dispatchers.Main

    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        job.cancel()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're observing `state` in `HomeForm`, so you have to update the `state` object in the ViewModel for a UI update to be triggered, not just a single property.
Changing your update function to

```
fun update(key: String, value: String) {
   Log.d("home","viewmodel $key = $value")
   when (key) {
      "numberplate" -> {
         state.value = state.value?.copy(numberplate = value)
      }
   }
}
```

should do the trick.